# Unable to rename all the files in a folder

Tags: php, rename, file-rename

I've been trying to change the file extension of all the picture files in a folder using the following snippet:

```
$dh = opendir('JS2C'); 
$files = array(); 
while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) { 
    if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..') {
        $file = pathinfo($file);
        rename($file, $new . '.jpg');
    }
}
```

I get the following warning messages:

```
SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
Warning: rename(ANAZODO.gif,ANAZODO.jpg): 
The system cannot find the file specified. (code: 2) in C:\wamp2\www\ckcportal\batch2.php on ...
```

The folder that contains the files is in the same folder with the `PHP` script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing directory for rename

```
$d = 'JS2C/'
$dh = opendir($d); 
while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) { 
    if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..') {
        //$file_no_ext = substr($file, 0,strrpos($file,'.'));// before php 5.2 

        $path_parts = pathinfo($file); // php 5.2
        $file_no_ext =  $path_parts['filename'];  // php 5.2

       rename($d.$file, $d.$file_no_ext . '.jpg');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to supply the full path, from the error you are receiving, it looks like you are just giving the file name.

```
rename('/path/to/old/file', '/path/to/new/file');
```

And why are you using `$file = pathinfo($file);`? [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) creates an assoc. array from information of `$file` which should be giving you the full path. If you take this out, it should work.

Unless you need to following:

```
$info = pathinfo($file);
$path = $info['dirname']

$new_file = $path . '/' . 'newfile.ext';

rename($file, $new_file);
```